# java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1

Tags: java

I read text file using following code

```java
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(path));
Set<String> set = lines.filter(s -> !s.startsWith("#") && 
                                    !s.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

in file México word thats why it throws excption.
How to handle this excpetion

Comment: It sounds like your file isn't in UTF-8. Either change it so that it *is* UTF-8 (which would be best, IMO) or specify the `Charset` when you call `Files.lines`.

Comment: I used UTF-8 but in that € is converted into ?

Comment: It shouldn't be - but it's possible that how you're then using the results doesn't support the Euro symbol.

Answer (score -1):

I handle this exception as bellow ,you can choose your suitable charset
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YYi2.png)

Comment: Please don't add images of code. Add the code itself to the answer.